# $\mathbb{N}$ is a Compact Space with the Co-finite Topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be the topological space on the set $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology.

I am having a hard time seeing why this is compact in the topological sense. If each open $n$-hood on $X$ contains all but finitely many elements of $\mathbb{N}$ Then how can a finite subcover exist? I can see how the complement of each of my neighbourhoods could be compact, is that somehow the same thing?

Comment: I'm trying to see why the theorem below needs Hausdorff;
If X is compact and Hausdorff then every compact subset of X is closed.
I can see why this would fail on $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology, but I can't see why my topology is compact.

Comment: A finite cover means a finite family of neighborhoods, not that the neighborhoods themselves are finite sets.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I knew it was something simple!

Comment: You didn't realize it, but you knew that already.  Consider the usual topology for $\Bbb R$.  Every open set (except $\varnothing$) is infinite.  So you could have encountered the same puzzle by asking how there could be any compact subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For every open set there are only finite number of $n$'s not covered by it.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting mixed up. You & @MJD above helped me out perfectly!

Comment: @SanFranMath MJD probably diagnosed the source of your problem. Again: If you have an infinite cover, take one open set and a finite number of open sets containing the remaining elements.